# how to read sqlite data into pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihW2M.jpg)

I want to read sqlite's table, named 230209010, but it is wrong.

I do not known what happens.

I have checked the table name with .tables in the terminal.

Could anyone know what happened? and What can I do now?

I have checked the table name with .tables in the terminal.

Comment: Please provide error message as text, not image

Answer (score 0):

SQLite needs table names starting with numbers to be bracketed.

```sql
SELECT * FROM [230209010];
```

[Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a
question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)